# including javascript in a ".vm" file

Tags: javascript

This is my velocity(.vm) file. I need to write a code such that if I select an option from any 1 dropdown the other dropdwon gets disabled and if I choose the "--Select--" option, both dropdowns are enabled.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="pvncId" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Provincienaam</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<select id="pvncId" name="pvncId" title="Province" class="form-control 
form_select">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
  #foreach($pvnc in $provincelist)
 <option value="$pvnc.gml_id">${pvnc.provincienaam}</option>
#end
</select>
<span class="help-block" id="help-block-service"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="gemId" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gemeentenaam</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<select id="gemId" name="gemId" title="Gemeenten" class="form-control 
form_select">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
  #foreach($gem in $gemeentenlist)
 <option value="$gem.gml_id">${gem.gemeentenaam}</option>
#end
</select>
<span class="help-block" id="help-block-service"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the values in the dropdown are populated from the database.